# SQLKata Multiple From Sub Selects

Tags: c#, sqlkata

I am trying to write the following statement is my desired output:

```
SELECT TABLE1.COLUMN_1
  FROM (SELECT '0' AS COLUMN_1 FROM DUAL) TABLE1,
       (SELECT '0' AS COLUMN_1 FROM DUAL) TABLE2
 WHERE TABLE1.COLUMN_1 = TABLE2.COLUMN_1;
```

This is the code SQLKata:

```
<PackageReference Include="SqlKata" Version="3.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="SqlKata.Execution" Version="3.2.3" />

using SqlKata;
using SqlKata.Execution;

var q1= new Query("DUAL").Select("'0' AS COLUMN_1");
var q2= new Query("DUAL").Select("'0' AS COLUMN_1");
var q3= new Query().From(q1, "table1")
                   .From(q2, "table2")
                   .Where("table1.COLUMN_1","table2.COLUMN_1")
                   .Select("table1.COLUMN_1")
                   .FirstOrDefault<string>();
```

This results in:

```
SELECT TABLE1.COLUMN_1
  FROM (SELECT '0' AS COLUMN_1 FROM DUAL) TABLE2
 WHERE TABLE1.COLUMN_1 = TABLE2.COLUMN_1;
```

It looks like it the second From overwrites the first from.

Another example:

```
var phones = new Query("Phones");
var laptops = new Query("Laptops");

var query = new Query().From(phones, "P").From(laptops, "L")
```

Results, notice Phones is not in the query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      [Laptops]
  ) AS [L]
```

Comment: Please give more details and what is your desired output.

Comment: Dear EJD would u please let me know the name of package that you are using for building query? which package does <Query> belong to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically an inner join query, so you can rewrite it like this one:

```
SELECT TABLE1.COLUMN_1
  FROM (SELECT '0' AS COLUMN_1 FROM DUAL) TABLE1 JOIN
       (SELECT '0' AS COLUMN_1 FROM DUAL) TABLE2
 ON TABLE1.COLUMN_1 = TABLE2.COLUMN_1;
```

and this is the equivalent syntax in SqlKata

```
var q1 = new Query("DUAL").Select("'0' AS COLUMN_1");
var q2 = new Query("DUAL").Select("'0' AS COLUMN_1");

var query = new Query()
    .From(q1, "table1")
    .Join(
        q2.As("table2"), // note how the As() method is used to alias this sub query 
        j => j.On("table1.COLUMN_1","table2.COLUMN_1")
    )
    .Select("table1.COLUMN_1");
```